# 24V battery to drive a 5V arduino speed controller and a motor

Tags: microcontroller, motor, design, voltage-divider, circuit-design

I would like to use a 24V power supply to power (1) an arduino that will act as a speed controller and (2) a DC motor by using an NPN transistor. I am wondering how I can use the same battery to split the power between the collector of the transistor and the arduino. I first thought of using a voltage divider for the arduino, but then the excess voltage gets grounded. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: First do some research - there are lots of projects out on the interweb that involve 24V motors and arduinos.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I accomplish this?

I would buy or build a small buck converter that takes a range of input voltages (say 18 V to 36 V) and delivers your logic supply (5 V or 3V3) for the Arduino. Maybe one of these: -

[image]

The NPN transistor would probably have its emitter grounded with the motor wired between collector and 24V - you will need a flyback diode across the motor of course. The base of the NPN will need to be driven through a resistor from the Arduino.

If you want speed control you have to use PWM for the above set-up.